# Error in reading shapefile in R

Tags: r

When I try to read shapefiles in a loop in R, it always reports

> "Error in .local(x, ...) : file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not
>   TRUE " .

The code that I use to read the shapefile is

```
 "city.i=shapefile(citynames1[i]) "
```

where citynames1 is a vector of shapefile names with the extension of `.shp`.

Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: Have you looked into the R package 'shapefiles'? That will probably provide the answer.

Comment: Just use the filenames without extension. That might work.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried to read the shapefile without the extension, but it doesn't work. Finally, I  succeeded to read the shapefile using the sf package. The reason why shapefile function doesn't work is that the filename is in Chinese. Thanks again for your kind suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is connected with locale setting on your PC. In my case `sf` package were able to write files with Chinese characters, please see the code below:

```
# simulation
library(sf)
file_name <- system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")
nc <- st_read(file_name)


# write shape
st_write(nc, "你好.shp")


# clear & read
rm(list = ls())
nc <- st_read("你好.shp")
plot(nc)
```

Output:

[image: maps]